# bmGlyph alternative for windows (Bitmap font generator)

Tags: 2d, graphics, fonts

I have been using this tool (bmGlyph http://www.bmglyph.com/) to create fonts from apple machines, but now, I'm on windows and need a program with same / more features. The main features about this program is the possibility of give a grandient color and apply a texture to each glyph. Could anybody recommend something like this for windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only know a basic one: [BMFont by AngelCode](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/). So, I'd be interested in this answer as well.

Comment: You can always use GIMP/Photoshop or other similar tools. If you need to do this programmatically/at runtime, you might want to look into MS' DirectWrite API

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to create a bitmap font from a true type font](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/tool-to-create-a-bitmap-font-from-a-true-type-font)

Comment: I think it isn't a duplicate. I have checked (roughtly) the applications that are exposed and they bitmap fonts but I can't use gradients or textures on every glyph. As I exposed this is really important to me because it gives a really nice look.